# h3 text its been overflown

Tags: html, css

In the webpage there is an `h3` tag  with some with but the txt that contains its shown out of the h3,Itried to change the `h3` `max-width` but the text is still shown out of the `h3`

```
<section class="link-interview-section">
        <div class="custom-mobile-row">
            <div class="half-row" id="div1">
                <h3>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </h3>
                <h4>
                    Lorem Ipsum
                </h4>
                <div class="btn-link btn-white">
                    <a href="<% url(t('meta.bbbb_simval_url')) %>">
                        <span class="btn-link-text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
                        <span class="arrow-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="half-row" id="div2">
                <h3>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                </h3>
                <h4>
                    Lorem Ipsum
                </h4>
                <div class="btn-link btn-white">
                    <a href="<% url(t('meta.aaa_url')) %>">
                        <span class="btn-link-text">Lorem Ipsum</span>
                        <span class="arrow-right"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

and the css(sass)

```
.link-interview-section{
    .custom-mobile-row{
        width: 100%;
        /*para no dejar un espacio entre los div*/
        font-size: 0px;
    }
    .half-row{
        width: 50%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 500px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin:0;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: Gelasio, serif;
        color:#FFFFFF !important;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 1.2;
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .half-row {
            width: 100%;
        }
    }
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .custom-mobile-row{
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    }
    #div1{
        background-image: url('#{$gImagesPath}g6-1-desktop.jpg');
        @include breakpoint(medium down){
            background-image: url('#{$gImagesPath}g6-1-mobile.jpg');
        }
    }
    #div2{
        background-image:  url('#{$gImagesPath}gs6-2-desktop.jpg');
        @include breakpoint(medium down){
            background-image: url('#{$ImagesPath}g.jpg');
        }
    }
    body{
        margin: 0;
    }   
}
```

How   can I set the h3 with css to adapt the text to the h3 width?

Answer (score 2):

```
white-space: break-spaces;
```

This will allow your text to go to the next line.